# Tabu : I tried to run simple sample code from manual. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: tables, tcolorbox, tabu

First I was planning to put `tabu` into `tcolorbox` - failed.

Then I tried to compile sample code from `tabu` [manual](https://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf) - failed again!

Is something wrong with that code or I don't know something I should?

**Environment:**

Miktex Console 4.1,

TexnicCenter 2.02(64bit),

mode: LaTeX=>PDF,

**Output:**

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1)

12 X `Undefined control sequence`

**MWE:**

...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{chapter}
    
    \section{section}
    
    \subsection{subsection}
    
    Some text ...
    
    \taburowcolors[2] 2{green!25 .. yellow!50}
    \begin{tabu}{*2{X[c]}} \toprule
        \repeatcell2{
        rows=5,
        text/col1=test,
        text/col2=row \thetaburow} \\
        test & other row \thetaburow \\ \cmidrule
        {1-2}
        test & other row \thetaburow \\
        test & other row \thetaburow \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
    
    Some other text ... 
\end{document}
```

...

What I need is:

- free row/cell coloring,
- lines between rows having defined width,
- a bit of precision when defining columns width and table width.

Now I try to exploit examples in `colortbl` manual.

Comment: Tabu is currently unmaintained and contains quite some unfixed bug. See: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu I therefore suggest using a different method/package to typeset your table.

Comment: Besides the, unfortunately, valid  comment from leandriis It would also be of importance to know which version of (La)TeX you are using and what the errors are you see.

Comment: Yes, I found that info on page after I had posted question. Still I need some advise, because there are plenty of packages. What I need is:  (1) free row/cell coloring,  
(2) lines between rows having defined width, 
(3) a bit of precision when defining columns width and table width. 
Now I try to exploit examples in `colortbl` manual.

Comment: You should have a look at `nicematrix`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny : You've done nice work. It seems that is what I need for now. If you would put, into manual, lisf of dependencies before every example, it would be excellent. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom Bombadil: Good suggestion...